# System.Drawing.Image EntityType 'Image' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, mapping, entity-framework-4.1, system.drawing.imaging

I'm using EF Code First and Data Scaffolding and have an entity that contains a property of type

```
public System.Drawing.Image Image { get; set; }
```

When initialsing the DB context to create the DB i get the following errors:

> System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: :
> EntityType 'Image' has no key defined.
> Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet:
> EntityType: EntitySet Images is based
> on type Image that has no keys
> defined.

Any ideas on how to get arround this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following @Gats answer - you cannot map all classes to EF. EF understands only basic types and each mapped class must be either recognized as entity or complex type. So your `Impage` must be defined as:

```
public byte[] Image { get; set; }
```

By marking it as `byte[]` EF will understand that it must be stored as `varbinary` in SQL server. EF doesn't support custom types or custom initializers so you cannot say EF that your `Image` should be anything else.

If you want to expose `Image` as System.Drawing.Image as well you can do something like:

```
public System.Drawing.Image GetBitmap()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Image))
    {
        return System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: + @Gats Thanks for your replies. I certainly am finding myself chaning my POCO model quite a bit to accomodate the ORM. It's pitty there's no custom mapping I could declare in the context class.

Answer (score 5):

This is because EF cannot track a class that's not available to it (like System.Drawing.Image) and it sees your "image" property as being it's own entity and expects mapping information for it (including a primary key).

If you are storing an image in your database, you will be better off using a binary property and then adding the actual Image property as a read only non-mapped property that converts the binary to an image file. System.Drawing.Image is NOT a datatype that can just map to SQL.

When you have done that and you want to prevent a property from being mapped use the following data annotation:

```
[NotMapped]
public .....
```